# Unable to add PopupPage to project in Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup

I would like to use Rg.Plugins.Popup for Xamarin.Forms but unfortunately I cannot add PopupPage to the project. I am using VIsual Studio 2017. In `AddNewItem` window there is no PopupPage at all.

I tried to add `ContentPage` instead like this:

```
public partial class CustomPopupPage : ContentPage
{
    public CustomPopupPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

but whenever i try to change type `ContentPage` to `PopupPage` I get following error: `Partial declarations of 'CustomPopupPage' must not specify different base classes.`

The problem is that second partial class is in auto-generated file `CustomPopupPage.xaml.g.cs` and I cannot modify that file because each time application is compiling it rewrites that file.

I think I am missing something obvious here because demo is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PopupPage` is a subclass of ContentPage .So you have to add a new `ContentPage` and change the superclass both in xaml and code benind .

Firstly , install the package **Rg.Plugins.Popup** from nuget in share project and specific platform (iOS and Android).

The plugin requires to be initialized. To use a PopupPage inside an application, each platform application must initialize the Rg.Plugins.Popup. This initialization step varies from platform to platform and is discussed in the following sections.

#### iOS ->AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
   Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
      
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
   LoadApplication (new App ());
   return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
}
```

#### Android->MainActivity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);

   Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
        
   Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
   LoadApplication (new App ());
}
```

#### xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyPopupPage">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <Label
            Text="Test"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

#### in code behind

```
public partial class MyPopupPage : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
  public MyPopupPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
    base.OnAppearing();
  }
}
```

### Update

It seems an existing issue of vs 2017 , on VS 2019 it works fine . And I will post this issue to product teams .

Comment: I know how to do it because I have a working demo. The problem is that I cannot change ContentPage to PopupPage in code behind because of errors. Could you try to reproduce this bug?

Comment: Did you change the class type of xaml?

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is in CustomPopupPage.xaml.g.cs which is not updates after my changes. Can it be VS problem?

Comment: What is the version of XF?

Comment: This was a VS issue. I updated to 2019 and now it's working.

Comment: I have post my answer ,can you accept it ？Which will help more people.