# Is it possible to make a legacy on contentPage in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, oop, xamarin.forms

I wanted to create an abstract class with methods. I wanted to inherit a view of this abstract class but the following error appears:
X type partial declarations should only specify different classes of bases.

```
//My abstract class
public abstract class AbstractInit : ContentPage
{...}

//My inheritance
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyView : AbstractInit{...}
```

Comment: What is the version of VS ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: It seems an existing issue of vs 2017 ,update it to vs 2019 .Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010346/unable-to-add-popuppage-to-project-in-visual-studio

Comment: And you can firstly run it directly , sometimes the IDE will ignore the issue .Don't forget to set the superclass in xaml at the same time .

Comment: I'll try your solution

Comment: Tell me the result if it works or not.

Comment: It does not work, even with VS19.

Comment: Share your sample and I will check it on  my side.